# Change stack order of Bootstrap divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three divs:

```
<div class="col-md-5" id="A"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 visible-lg" id="B"></div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="C"></div>
```

The #B div is not displayed in tablets/mobile. What I want is to stack the #C div **above** the #A div when in mobile.

I have played around with push and pull but cannot get the desired result.

Comment: id and classnames must not begin with a digit.

Comment: Fixed, simplified my divs for demo.

Comment: Multiply the content, put it above A and let it display only on mobile. Hide bottom C on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the content, put it in front of A:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 visible-xs" id="C"></div>
 <div class="col-md-5" id="A"></div>
 <div class="col-md-3 visible-lg" id="B"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs" id="C"></div>
```

and adjust ID's accordingly to be unique for document .